# Removing an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling, click

I'm currently playing around with creating a new image slider for a project, but had a question. The task is to have an image displayed on page that will open the full size onclick. However, I'd like to make it so the function goes away and the image returns to the original state onclick again.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fullscreen</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="//path" onClick="full()" id="image" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function full() {
            $(function () {
                $('#image').on('click', function () {
                    $(this).width(1000);
                });
            }); 
        }
    </script>
</body>   
</html>
```

The image opens in a larger state which is good, but how would I implement a second onclick function to take away the first?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you want to remove the event listenner or scale down the image on second click?

Comment: I'd like to return the image to how it was, so I'm guessing that would be removing the event listener

Comment: Removing the event listener wouldn't revert what you did to the image. It just removes the event from triggering your callback function again

Comment: FYI, there is no need to have `$(function () { ... })` inside the click handler. At the moment the function is executed, the DOM is already loaded.

Comment: Patrick, would you have any suggestions how I go about this then?

Comment: Another (simple) suggestion to remove previously attached events is to use jQuery "unbind", take a look at: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Rodrigo, I for some reason couldn't get the unbind function to work! That was my first go-to, and I ended up posting this because it wouldn't work with me. You stack guys are awesome though, I sincerely appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take an event previously assigned use

```
$('#image').off('click')
```

To scale back the image, use

```
var size = 0;
function full() {
    $(function () {
        $('#image').on('click', function () {
            if (size === 0) {
                size = $(this).width();
                $(this).width(1000);
            } else {
                $(this).width(size);
                size = 0;                     
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you so much!

I figured I'd need an else statement, but the way I was writing it just wouldn't work to my benefit. You're fantastic, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

### What you're literally asking for :

The code below shows you how to do what you're literally asking for :

1. After the first click, You change the width to 1000, you remove the inital click handler and add a new click handler to reset the width
2. After the second click, you reset the with and remove the second click handler
3. Any clicks after the second click don't do anything anymore

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fullscreen</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="//path" id="image" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#image').on('click', function() {
                $(this)
                    .width(1000)
                    .off('click')
                    .on('click', function() {
                        $(this)
                            .width('')
                            .off('click');
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</body>   
</html>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nv7gLb3L/2/) for a working demo.

---

### What you probably want :

What you probably want, is just a single click handler that toggles the width of your image.

The best way to do that, would be something like this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fullscreen</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="//path" id="image" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#image').on('click', function() {
                var me = $(this);
                me.width(me.width() !== 1000 ? 1000 : '');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>   
</html>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nv7gLb3L/7/) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

If width is `1000px` then remove it otherwise set it to `1000` like following.

```
<img src="//path" id="image" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#image').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).width() == '1000')
            $(this).width('');
        else
            $(this).width(1000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the onclick listener, but you need to fix a few things. You have an inline onclick callback which was actually calling the `full` function that attaches a new click listener over and over again, eventually causing the click handler to be called 2^n times.

You can just keep the one in the code, and inside it check the current width of the image in order to choose what happens when you click it (assuming 50px is the starting width):

```js
$('#image').on('click', function() {
  $(this).width($(this).width() != 1000 ? 1000 : 50);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  transition: width 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/518084-background-hd.jpg"  id="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `class` & `toggleClass`

```
function full() {
    $(function () {
        $('#image').on('click', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('changeWidth');
        });
    }); 
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/k8p47xj9/1/)